# Incompatible types. Found: 'javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication', required: 'java.lang.Void'

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I get this error when I try to send a mail using JavaMail API.
code :

```
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator()){
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(Util.EMAIL,Util.PASSWORD);
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is `Session` here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `)` at the wrong place:

```
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(Util.EMAIL, Util.PASSWORD);
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

Depending on the surrounding code this change will introduce some syntax errors that need to be fixed